# Exclude specific file from find

Tags: linux, shell, find

I am trying to find all .py files under specific path except only one specific **init**.py file. Please note that I dont want to exclude other **init**.py files.

I tried `find risk/bouncer/test/tt/ -name "*.py" ! -name __init__.py` but it ignores all **init**.py files.

I want to ignore only `__init__.py` file from `risk/bouncer/test/tt/` and all other files should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-path` option for this requirement:

```
find risk/bouncer/test/tt/ -name "*.py" -not -path risk/bouncer/test/tt/__init__.py
```

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile I had found `find risk/bouncer/test/tt/ -name "*.py" | sed '/tt\/__init__.py/d'` but your solution is better.

Comment: Yes `sed` is unnecessary as `find` can easily handle this in single command.